# Source file of ROS

Tags: ros, source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there. I have installed ROS on Mac OS and found there are source files in most packages' src folder.
But in Ubuntu, ROS packages reside in `opt` folder and I can not find source file. What
is the difference?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206220/source-file-of-ros/) by [zurish](https://answers.ros.org/users/20878/zurish/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2015-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On an OSX installation, you compile all packages yourself, on your local machine. In order to do that, you need the sources, so you download them to your machine as one of the steps in the [OSX Installation](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/OSX/Homebrew/Source) tutorial.

On Ubuntu (or any platform for which ROS builds binary packages), users typically install the debians (or [.deb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deb_%28file_format%29)). These are build by the ROS [buildfarm](http://wiki.ros.org/buildfarm) (status [here](http://www.ros.org/debbuild/indigo.html)), and `apt-get` only downloads the `.deb` archives. Those archives typically only contain the *binaries* (ie: the results of the compilation steps) and not the *sources* (the input of the compilation process). That is the main reason you don't find the sources on a ROS Ubuntu installation that didn't do the [source install](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source).

It is perfectly possible for the author of the package however to include the sources in a `.deb`: all he needs to do is add an [install rule](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/installing_other.html) to his `CMakeLists.txt` which copies the sources into a directory which will be included in the `.deb`. Upon installation of the `.deb`, the user will then also find the sources on his system (probably somewhere under `/opt/ros/DISTRO/share/PKG_NAME/`).

Installing the sources in that way is not recommended though, as (at least on Debian/Ubuntu) you can get the sources for any `.deb` using: `apt-get source PKG_NAME` (no `sudo`). Note that this requires that you have a correct `deb-src ..` line in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` for the relevant repository.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zurish](https://answers.ros.org/users/20878/zurish/) on 2015-03-30**:
Thank you. Your answer explains.